# Angular - Function for on load and resize

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom directive that I want some logic (in an if statement) to be run when a page loads or when its resized.

So for the the page load I have the if statement at the start of the custom directive then again duplicated in the `on resize`.

However to avoid this duplication is it possible to do something like the below?

```
angular.element($window).on('resize' || 'load', function () {
    //my logic
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried .on('resize load', ... ?

Comment: That looks like it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply have the events names as a string separated with a space:

```
angular.element($window).on('resize load', function () {
    //my logic
}
```